# How to show multiple results from MySQL Array

Tags: php, sql, database, arrays

Here is my current code:

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_posts";
        $result = mysql_query($sql); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
        print $row['message'];
        }
```

My goal is to show all of the data in that SQL database through an array. But currently, it only shows the latest one and nothing else. How am I able to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove this line

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Apart from that it should display every message

Comment: Works great! So that means I should not specify the variable before to make it work?

Comment: What you're doing there is effectively removing the first row from the results. Each call to mysql_fetch_array moves on to the next row

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting the one row because you overwrite the $row variable with the values from your results array.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_posts";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    print $info['message'];
}
```

Change it to something like that.